# How can I remove bloatware Acer includes in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, bloatware

I bought an Acer laptop with Windows 7

At first I just installed Linux on it, but I need to run some Windows software and test websites in IE.

I could remove all the crap by hand, but is there a good utility that could do this for me?

Comment: Similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/20099/mass-uninstalling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PC Decrapifier](http://www.pcdecrapifier.com/) may help, but if anything's left behind, Revo Uninstaller should at least simplify the removeal process.